# Getting this weird gap between mirrored mesh, need help!

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, subdivision-surface, mirror

[image]

Hey Guys so I ve been following this tutorial by derek elliot for creating a shoe, I have followed his tutorial to a point where if I delete the faces to make space for a foot to set in, the effect is not what is in his video, for reference, here is what he gets....

[image]

**Any help is appreciated**

Answer (score 2):

In the modifier stack, put the *Mirror* above the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, otherwise it's the subdivided object that will be mirrored and not the inverse

Comment: Hi, when I do that the entire mesh suddenly disappears

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Oh I turned off gpu subdivision in the preferences tab, and it worked!! still, thanks for the help moon !!